# Increase rendering speed for the data coming from MSSQL for showing in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson, tiles, rendering

I have some polygon data which are coming from MSSQL server. Getting these data takes about 5 seconds and I have about 1600 Polygons. I would like to show a popup for each polygon (by clicking on them, helper method). The rendering time after getting this data for showing them in a Leaflet map takes about 40 seconds which is too long. How I can accelerate the rendering process?

My code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
                                  var map = L.map('map', {
                      center: [-37.357605, 175.089111],
                      minZoom: 2,
                      zoom: 5
                  })

                 L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                      attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, USGS, Intermap, iPC, NRCAN, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), Esri (Thailand), TomTom, 2012'
                  }).addTo(map);


                  var myURL = 'maps/images/'

                     var geometries = [];
   <!--GeoHelper is a class which select  data from MSSQL and converts WKT to JSON on demand and takes about 5 seconds --%>
             <% website.GeoHelper helper = new website.GeoHelper();

               foreach (var item in helper.GetSpatialData())
               { %>
    var myArea = L.polygon(<%=item.Polygon %> ,{ color: 'blue', weight: 4 }) .bindPopup('<a href="' + "text" + '" target="_blank">' + <%=item.id %> + '</a>').addTo(map);
                  <% } %>   
                  </script>
```

What I have tried:

Change basemap providers, I used OSM, not a dramatic improvment.

Comment: Is your question about rendering lots of polygons quickly, or getting content for a popup with WFS via GeoServer?

Comment: I started with rendering lots of Polygon and I found a solution for that, However, appreciate any better solution. With my current solution, Using WMS and WFS, I stuck in showing the popup. Not sure if I have to delete the updated part or leave it like that and raise another question for popup. Thanks

Comment: It is your question and because it has no answers posted you can decide which single thing you want to ask clearly here.  Asking more than one thing is likely to lead to it being closed as too broad.  Once you decide the single thing you want to ask, any details not relevant to that should be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.  I will eliminate one soon

Comment: A WMS will be much faster than a WFS, so it will depend on what you want to do with the data in your client (Leaflet)

Comment: Thank you. I need to also make the map clickable, I think I can not do that by WMS merely. I need to set and use WFS also in GeoServer. Right?

Comment: Map can be clickable, WMS supports the GetFeatureInfo request for that.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, Do you have an example for this? There are some examples on the Web, but not enough explanation.